# Trying to use fopen and fprintf with matlab, only writing once

Tags: matlab, input, printf, fopen

I'm having trouble writing to a file here... I must be making a simple mistake but I can't find it. Anyways, here's the code:

```
ages = 1;
while (ages > 0)
    fileID = fopen('age.txt', 'w'); %opens file
    ages = input('Enter an age (negative to quit): '); %user input
    if(ages > 0) %so it doesn't add on the break number
        fprintf(fileID, '%d\r\n', ages);
    end
end

fclose(fileID);
```

My problem is that it writes nothing to the file. If I remove the if statement it writes only -1 to the file (using -1 as the negative 'quit' number).
What am I missing?

Comment: Easy, your `fopen` command is inside the loop ... so each time "it open file for writing. Discard existing contents, if any" (`w` mode). Put `fopen` outside `while` loop

Comment: Start by moving `fileID = fopen('age.txt', 'w'); %opens file` before `while`. It's enough to open the file only once.

Comment: @CitizenInsane You might want to put that in an answer. If only to get the overview nice and tidy and let others see this is answered.

Comment: @CitizenInsane , just do it. :) You were faster than me. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy,

Your `fopen` command is inside the loop ... so each time "it opens file for writing and discard existing contents, if any" (`w` mode).

Put `fopen` outside while loop.

Comment: Thank you! I'm not sure how to select this as an answer or upvote it, but this is exactly what I needed!